# Prohibiting changing of home page and launcher

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher, home-directory

I want to be able to prohibit the change of the order of the icons in the launcher and from people changing the home page in firefox. Is there a way to do this?

So far I figured out a way to do it so that when they change the desktop background when they reboot it will go back to the default background no matter what. Can I use the same method for icons etc. if so how would i start the code?

Code for background:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/ubuntu_1.jpg"
```

Comment: Would you want the entire Firefox preferences and settings to be reset, or just the homepage? I don't think this is possible to not permit the changing of this setting (same with the launcher).

Comment: The entire firefox preferences and settings to be reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the launcher, it can be easily set like this:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'application://unity-control-center.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
```

I covered this more in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/490572/178596).

As for the Firefox home page, that is set in the profile settings so is harder to set directly using a command. A simple way round this would be to remove the Firefox profiles using this command:

```
rm -r ~/.mozilla/firefox
```

<sup>*Don't run this on a system where you want to keep your Firefox settings etc intact.*</sup>

This can be added to 'Startup Applications' to remove the Firefox profiles on login. This has to be added wrapped in `bash -c "... ..."` so it executes correctly:

[image]

Also note a alternative to all this may be to [create a Guest Account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14222/how-to-add-a-guest-account-without-a-password)

Comment: Quick question; I used the launcher code you gave me and added the applications I needed. But there is one application I added that doesn't seem to work and that is the calculator.

'code' gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://firefox.desktop', 'application://skype.desktop', 'application://vlc.desktop', 'application://calculator.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"

Comment: That does work (in 14.04 atleast - I might of miss-copied the one in this version, try the fully detailed referenced version of my answer (thats also details how to get the launcher as you want it set up). (Edit: yeah, i missed out a `"`)

Comment: I am using 14.04 and used that exact code but the calculator won't show up. Everything else that I want to show up is showing up. Thanks for all your help! It is greatly appreciated it!

Comment: @Moktao - your welcome :)  getting the output from the `get` command is the best way - remember to check the quotes...