# How to create guest account in Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: guest-session

There isn't an option for a guest account at logon screen. I can create a user with limited access but I want any saved data or changed settings be removed/reset at logout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a guest account without a password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14222/how-to-add-a-guest-account-without-a-password)

Comment: [**karthick87's answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/14223/283843) [second link](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/05/24/how-to-create-a-guest-user-account-on-ubuntu-10-04/2/) ^^

Comment: @KasiyA: The OP seems to be aware of the options. How do those links clarify that there is no option to access a true guest session (where everything is reset at logout) from the login screen in 10.04?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `gdm-guest-session` package. But in 10.04 there is no way to enter a guest session from the login screen; you can only enter it from within a regular session.

If you switch to 12.04 or 14.04, you'll get what you ask for.